# how to debug .net assembly when it's being used by other process

Tags: c#, .net-assembly, visual-studio-debugging

I have 2 projects A and B written in C# in VS. A is treated as Host applocation, B is a dll.
A will load B at runtime by Assembly.LoadFrom and Call B's method. **My question is how can I debug B when A Is executing B's dll.**
I have source code of both projects. but when I Attach B to process A. VS told me B.dll is being used by another process which is A.
So I can't set breakpoint of B's code because B's symbol is not loaded. How can I debug B when B is being used by A? thanks!

Comment: Open the B project.  Project + Properties, Debug tab.  Choose "Start external program" and select A.exe.  Set breakpoints and press F5.

Answer (score 1):

First start the executable project. Then attach your dll project to exe project using *Attach to Process* option.

In Visual Studio, you can do this by,

Click on Debug menu --> Chose Attach to process option.

You will see list of all running process, choose appropriate one, and you can debug your dll code.

Comment: hi,thanks for your reply,I can debug B using your method,but when B is being used By A, B can't be debugged.

Comment: @steven At a time process will be attached with only one debugger. Better way to add dll project to your solution, but first see, it should not mess with your remaining project structure.

Comment: I wanna load dll projects through user operation.Like Unity3D, it let's you open a dll project, then run scripts from the dll and debug the scripts through  debugger at runtime

Comment: You can't debug a *dll*. You can only debug a *process*. The only way to debug a dll is to load it into a process and debug that.